# Trying to put the pieces together - JavaScript, HTML, PHP and reloading content

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am currently building a CMS for a company I recently started working for. We're building the CMS with an MCV structure. I am familiar with JavaScript, PHP, HTML5 and CSS3. I also build responsive features using JQuery.

Now I have to make a content manager with a sidebar with settings. With that sidebar you can e.g. change the background color, add a title or a background image to the content in the main section. The website has to automatically update (a part) of the content with that setting.

I'm trying to understand the process and putting the different languages back together. For example: You change a setting, eg a color, my process is as following:

1. The color in the sidebar changes the value in the Javascript.
2. Javascript then updates that value displayed with HTML on sidebar. `<With a JQuery function?>`
3. The value of Javascript is send to the PHP with `<something>`?
4. The PHP then generates a entire new page with this new setting with `<something>`
5. `<Something>` then refreshes a part of the content and thus changes the color.

Every bit with quotes are things I don't understand.

How does the process of this goes and with what do you update the browser, AJAX?

I don't know where to ask this question so if you might fill in some gaps I be very thankful!

**Edit**
An example from which this question arose:

I can drag an element from a left bar into the page. This adds a PHP function with Javascript, which echos a HTML section of columns with text onto the main page. I've created the element with PHP and the JavaScript was already there. Now I am adding a settings bar that generates buttons en settings which can alter the look of that element. I've creates this sidebar in PHP.
I understand how the PHP works with getting values from the database and generating this into a HTML. I understand how you can target a ID or an class in HTML with JavaScript. I don't understand, however, how you can do that effectively on a large scale. Like in an CMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways you could go about doing this. Here is just one way the process might go.

1. A [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) event handler is attached to an element that accepts user input.

   ```
   $("#colorpicker").change(function() {
       // Code here.
   });
   ```
2. The form element is changed, and the code within the handler is executed, modifying the style of the sidebar.

   ```
   $("#sidebar").css("background-color", $(this).val());
   ```
3. An [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) request is sent to a [php](/questions/tagged/php) script.

   ```
   var color = $(this).val();

   $.ajax({
       method: "POST",
       url: "change_sidebar.php",
       data: { color : color }
   });
   ```
4. The [php](/questions/tagged/php) script process the request, and stores it into some sort of [database](/questions/tagged/database).
5. Next time your page loads, [php](/questions/tagged/php) will set the initial color of the sidebar to be the color that you stored. However, until your page loads again, the color has already changed for the client, and nothing more needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to do the update asynchronously you can use a jquery function, or, you can create a form that does it and then have PHP update the color code as the page reloads.
2. That works, or you can do it with a form as stated in 1.
3. jQuery's `$.ajax()` function will do nicely.
4. ..with PHP.. that's what it's for. It doesn't need anything else.
5. If you're only refreshing part of it, then you'd use jQuery/JS, perhaps while employing PHP to update the server.

I don't know if you were expecting someone to write all this code for you or what but if you have specific questions please post them. This question is really vague. Normally we like to see what you've tried and exactly what the problem is.

Comment: What I am trying to understand is the process. I can program most of the part fine, I just want to know how to connect all of it together. I am currently using JQuery, but I thought that the little amount of selectors might not be enough. I can learn everything. I just need a pointer in the right direction. And by understanding how it all works together, I can see what I am missing

Comment: @Abayob I'd like to help you man, but like I said your questions are **extremely** vague. Can you narrow the question down to one specific problem or question for me?

Comment: Thank you! I added an example.